# Creating Parent/Child views in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

We have two models with parent-child relationship.

```java
@Entity
public class Parent extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long parentid;
    public String parentname;
    @OneToMany
    Child achild;
}

@Entity
public class Child extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long childid;
    public String childname;
    @ManyToOne
    Parent aparent;
}
```

We need to create a single view where we can both create and display children.
How can we create such a view?

Comment: Maybe you could read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaTemplates and then ask more precise question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bazillion ways to implement this, but the bare bones (HTML only) would be to render a page with a given parent and its children, with a HTML form to enter / edit children.

First, change your Parent's declaration of its children, from...

```
@OneToMany
Child achild;
```

... to something like...

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="aparent", targetEntity=Child.class) 
List<Child> children;
```

Assuming you are using eBean, add a finder:

```
static Model.Finder<Long, Parent> find = new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, Parent.class);
```

Your controller will look up a parent and its children, and hand the Parent to the template:

```
public static Result showParent(Long parentId) {
   Parent parent = Parent.find.fetch("children").where().eq("id", parentId).findUnique();
   return ok(parentTemplate.render(parent));
}
```

Your template parentTemplate.scala.html will accept that Parent object, render the appropriate parent fields, and iterate across the children, showing details on each:

```
@(parent: Parent)
<html>

...

<h1>Parent: @parent.parentName</h1>

@for(child <- parent.children) {
    <h2>@child.childName</h2>
}

<form ...>

</html>
```

Again, there are a lot of ways to implement it, but this is the most straightforward way to get started with Play's Scala template engine.

Comment: Thank you. This takes care of displaying the data very well. We also need to allow users to create both parent and multiple child records in the same form and post the data in a single request. Once the parent record is inserted into the database, we need to insert the child records with the same parentid of the newly created parent.

Comment: A great starter sample of editing using Play's helper functions, including form binders and Scala helpers, is found in the 'computer-database' sample. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/0f6a93bc403267a7fbaf0b704fb7857a074cbf4b/samples/java/computer-database  Take a look at the views, specifically editForm.scala.html and the related controller methods in Application.java

Comment: In the same computer database example, I tried having the form for adding a new computer in the list page itself. I made the following changes. list.render(
                Computer.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter),
                sortBy, order, filter,computerForm
            )
Also added @(computerForm: Form[Computer]) in list.scala.html - @main {

@(computerForm: Form[Computer])

Comment: When I run the application I see Form(of=class models.Computer, data={}, value=None, errors={}) displayed in the form.

Comment: With the "@(computerForm: Form[Computer])" statement, you are just rendering out the "toString" method of the form helper object. The Form object is not a complete HTML form, it is a helper object that provides shortcuts in working with forms. Take another look at the sample in the computer-database app. The form helper is used to wrap the set of input elements, not to render them.

Comment: I used @createForm(computerForm) and I now have inserting and displaying records in the same screen. Next, I need to look at how to have inserting and viewing child records in the same screen.